# how to make Dynamically Cell size Adjustment According to UIlabel text size

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am Beginner to iOS, I was facing problem , How to make Custom Cell size is Adjusted to UILabel Size of text. also I cant display Long Dynamically text in UILabel Fully, its show only selected Rows, it displays only selected  line in Attribute inspector that much it will displays. how to fix this both problem. help me

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [_data count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    SingleTableViewCell *cell = (SingleTableViewCell *)[_mytable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil){
        cell = [[SingleTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.labelTitle.text=[_data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.labelcount.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", (arc4random() % 74)];
    return cell;
}
```

This my Table delegate code. I saw my CGrect for calculate text size etc, but i will not work here. 
I am using Xcode 6.1.1, and Objective-c .

Comment: where you calculate the text size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Autolayout` and set the borders of the label to the cell then in your `viewDidLoad` method do this:

```
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44; // or your default size
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

Comment: This will make your `cell`'s `height` dynamic.

Comment: I did, but cell label text will overlaps,  in single line @Islam Q